# Permission issue for an ECS Service to use an ALB

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy an ECS stack with an ALB using cloudformation, and i get an error at the Service creation, which seems to be a missing permission to access the load balancer.

Here is the error: `Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.`

Here is the service definition:

```
    "EcsService": {
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",
      "DependsOn": [
        "loadBalancer",
        "EcsServiceRole"
      ],
      "Properties":{
        "Cluster":{
          "Ref": "EcsCluster"
        },
        "DesiredCount":"1",
        "DeploymentConfiguration":{
          "MaximumPercent":100,
          "MinimumHealthyPercent":0
        },
        "LoadBalancers": [
          {
            "ContainerName": "test-web",
            "ContainerPort": "80",
            "TargetGroupArn" : {
              "Ref": "loadBalancer"
            },
          }
        ],
        "Role":{
          "Ref": "EcsServiceRole"
        },
        "TaskDefinition":{
          "Ref": "runWebServerTaskDefinition"
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the Load Balancer definition:

```
    "loadBalancer" : {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "testalb",
        "Scheme" : "internal",
        "Subnets" : [
          "subnet-b8217295",
          "subnet-ddaad2b8",
          "subnet-6d71fb51"
        ],
        "LoadBalancerAttributes" : [
          { "Key" : "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds", "Value" : "50" }
        ],
        "SecurityGroups": [
          { "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroupOpenWeb" },
          { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroupOpenFull" }
        ],
        "Tags" : [
          { "Key" : "key", "Value" : "value" },
          { "Key" : "key2", "Value" : "value2" }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Here is the IAM role the service should use:

```
    "EcsServiceRole": {
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement":[
            {
              "Effect":"Allow",
              "Principal":{
                "Service":[
                  "ecs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action":[
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path":"/",
        "Policies":[
          {
            "PolicyName":"ecs-service",
            "PolicyDocument":{
              "Statement":[
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                    "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                    "ec2:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource":"*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I didn't find if there is a specific namespace for ALB in IAM.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TargetGroupArn should be pointing to TargetGroup ARN, not ALB ARN, Currently, it is pointed to Load Balancer ARN.

```
          "TargetGroupArn" : {
              "Ref": "loadBalancer"
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
As of July 19th 2018, it is now possible to create a IAM Service-Linked Roles using CloudFormation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-servicelinkedrole.html.

```
   EcsServiceLinkedRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole"
    Properties:
      AWSServiceName: "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      Description: "Role to enable Amazon ECS to manage your cluster."
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**
Since AWS introduced [Service-Linked Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html), I no longer specify a role for my `AWS::ECS::Service`. It will default to the service linked role which has all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to remove ````"Role":{
          "Ref": "EcsServiceRole"
        }```` from the EcsService definition and i get the exact same error

Comment: For old AWS accounts or if you never created an ECS cluster by hand in the console, you have to run this command to have the role created: `aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name ecs.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: An error occurs saying it already exists running this command, and i found it with the UI, looks like the issue is coming from somewhere else...

Comment: Do you have full admin access to the AWS account because without it, it might affect your ability to the pass role operation required for service to assume the service linked role.

Comment: Having the exact same  issue but my stack is pointing to the to the correct Arn  "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "ServiceTargetGroup" }. The issue is sporadic and unable to find resolve.

Comment: After months of intermittent on-going issues with AWS regarding this matter AWS came back to say they were throttling us in the background, on the ELB. This is why the random and varied issues were appearing when deploying 3+ docker services via Cloudformation at the same time. The solution was nothing to do with IAM permissions, rather it was to increase the rate limit on the ELB via the "AWS Service Team". Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49736272/8323582